# Python pptx module related

Tags: python

I am looking for generating this type of plot given in ex. with python pptx.

I am not able to get data table given in plot and also the style and the combination of black color line chart.

Looking for little help. Thanks in advance

[Bar & line combo chart with data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymiK1.jpg)

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for quick reply.I know, this is not the best way to write code. I was just trying at initial level to make a ppt slide as posted. 
[PPT slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk9A0.jpg) 
I am not able to get data table as shown in plot and also the style and the combination of line chart and barchart (Margin column as shown in below excel image, i want in linechart with datatable whoch i have not shown here.)
[Excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmqu0.jpg)

```
    import openpyxl
    from pptx import Presentation
    from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
    from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
    from pptx.util import Inches
    from pptx.enum.chart import XL_LEGEND_POSITION
    from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
    # create presentation with 1 slide ------
    prs = Presentation()
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test_ppt.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.active


    fff = []
    for f in range(4,10):
        name_l = str(sheet['c'+str(f)].value)
        fff.append(name_l)

    noo = []
    for f in range(4,10):
        noo_l = str(sheet['b'+str(f)].value)
        noo.append(noo_l)  

    erp = []
    for f in range(4,10):
        noo_ll = str(sheet['d'+str(f)].value)
        erp.append(noo_ll)  


    aa = tuple(map(int, fff))
    ab = tuple(map(int, erp))

    chart_data = CategoryChartData()
    chart_data.categories = noo
    series1 = str(sheet['c'+str(3)].value);
    series2 = str(sheet['d'+str(3)].value);
    chart_data.add_series(series1, aa)   
    chart_data.add_series(series2, ab)       


    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
    graphic_frame = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data)
    chart = graphic_frame.chart
    chart.has_legend = True
    chart.legend.position = XL_LEGEND_POSITION.RIGHT
    chart.legend.include_in_layout = False
    prs.save('chart.pptx')




    #series = chart.series[0]
    ## ---series.format is a ChartFormat object, which in turn provides access to
    ##    the LineFormat object for that series---
    #line = series.format.line
    # ---change the line style, color, etc. the same way as for any other line---
    #line.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
```